# jQuery can't select element with hasClass("open") or is(":visible)

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to select an element based on hasClass("open") or is(":visible).

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="about">About</a>
        <div class="sub-nav-wrapper"> 
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

```js
if ($('ul.menu li div').hasClass("open")) {
    $(this).parent().children("a").css('background', '#666');
}
```

When hovering on the "About" link, the submenu shows below and a class is added to the div with the "sub-nav-wrapper" class. The class is called "open." But when user moves cursor into the submenu area the main link ("About") loses its hover color. So I'm trying to bring it back with JS. It doesn't work and I also tried `.is(":visible")` and used an alert to check it but the alert popped up every time, even before I did anything, just on page loading.

Comment: There's a lot more here going on than you're showing us.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle with the code as it stands?

Comment: `.hasClass` isn't a selector. It just returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the selected element has the class. Nothing in your code sets `this`.

Comment: What's the expected behaviour, exactly? The user hovers the link once and it changes its color, and it's never to be changed again?

Comment: Is that code supposed to be inside an event handler? Please show the whole function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.  First, an `if` statement like this will only be executed once, so it is not going to work as a listener.  Second, `.hasClass()` just returns a boolean, not a DOM element, so the `this` inside your `if` statement is not what you think it is.

I would handle this with a `mouseover` / `mouseout` event handler.  Try:

```
$('ul.menu li div').mouseover(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().children("a").css('background', '#666');
}).mouseout(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().children("a").css('background', '#original-bg-color');
});
```

You would need to replace `"#original-bg-color"` with the default background color for your nav links.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an dot to open... - > hasClass('.open')

Regards

Comment: The code is in a CMS site, and there is a menu module controlling the adding and removing of the "open" class. Expected behavior is when a user hovers over the top nav item (ex. About), the bg color of the link is yellow. And the submenu is revealed below and has a bg color to match. but when the cursor moves down into the submenu to select a link, the hover color on the parent goes away, so there's no yellow color behind the top link ("About"). I think the comment about the "this" not being set makes sense, but I don't know how to deal with that. –  james 5 mins ago

Comment: Even putting an alert in my if statement, wouldn't I get an alert popup if the div had the class of "open?" It gets the class on hovering over the top link, but I never get an alert. So the if statement should be true, but no alert.

Comment: try to solve this with pure css?

li.nav-item:hover a {color:purple}